# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The programe runs fine when GetCreatorLicense() is disabled I tried to setdata outside the loop but still getting 'Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.' error and then I put this function under useEffect, I just get console output but useState haven't changed

```
        const Getdata = async () => {
            let grabbedData = [];
            await firebase
              .database()
              .ref(`/users`)
              .orderByKey()
              .on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
                // console.log('snapshot....', snapshot);
                grabbedData.push(snapshot.val());
              });
            setUserdata(grabbedData);
            //   console.log('grabbedData....', grabbedData);
          };
        
          useEffect(() => {
            Getdata();
            // GetCreatorLicense();
          }, []);
        
  React.useEffect(() => {
    GetCreatorLicense();
  }, []);

  const GetCreatorLicense = () => {
    console.log("this is a GetCreatorLicense this got printted");
    let checkDis = false;
    let checkDealer = false;
    let checkSubDis = false;
    let checkMoneyCollector = false;
    let checkfranchise = false;
    Object.keys(userdata).map(function (key) {
      console.log("I am not printed", userdata[key]);
      let x = userdata[key];
      Object.keys(x).map(function (key2) {
        console.log("I am not printed either", x[user1.uid].create.distributor);
        if (x[user1.uid].create.distributor) {
          checkDis = true;
        }
        if (x[user1.uid].create.subDistributor) {
          checkSubDis = true;
        }
        if (x[user1.uid].create.delaer) {
          checkDealer = true;
        }
        if (x[user1.uid].create.moneyCollector) {
          checkMoneyCollector = true;
        }
        if (x[user1.uid].create.franchise) {
          checkfranchise = true;
        }
      });
    });
    if (checkDis) {
      setCanCreateDistributor(true);
    }
    if (checkSubDis) {
      setCanCreateSubDistributor(true);
    }
    if (checkDealer) {
      setCanCreateDealer(true);
    }
    if (checkMoneyCollector) {
      setCanCreateMoneyCollector(true);
    }
    if (checkfranchise) {
      setCanCreateFranchise(true);
    }
  };
```

Edit: the loop is not running but in snack it works fine.

Comment: If `GetCreatorLicense();` is called right from the functional component body and updates state this will trigger a render loop. Can you provide a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example? When you place `GetCreatorLicense();` in the `useEffect` what console output are you referring to? What/how are you validating state wasn't updated (other than logging state from the ***current*** render cycle)?

Comment: this is the link https://snack.expo.io/@mgonekar/quiet-fudge

Comment: ok I understand GetCreatorLicense update the state and then it reloads GetCreatorLicense called and thus loop goes then how do i prevent this I use useEffect and useCallback but I get output of console.log("this is a GetCreatorLicense"); but state has not updated

Comment: Where and how are you validating state isn't updating? I see only one enqueued state update in `setCanCreateDistributor(true);` on line 85, but `canCreateDistributor`'s initial state value is already `true`.

Comment: All the state are false by default and the ' userdata..create.. ' can be true or false and this data is comming from firebase can be updated by the other authorized user and the 'key2' is id of authorized  logged user

Comment: When do you want `GetCreatorLicense` to run? What is your expected result/behavior? I made some edits to your snack and I see state update normally as expected.

Comment: I dont find prev. code is there. but some code show u what I am trying to do. or share the link

Comment: Are you asking me if I would like to see a new/updated snack of what you are *actually* attempting to do? If so, then yes, please, we need to see what your real code is doing. You still haven't said when & where you want `GetCreatorLicense` to run, i.e. when the component mounts, whenever a specific value updates, every render?

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed changing state in the `useEffect`. `Getdata` is called from within `useEffect` and it is calling `setUserdata` which I assume is a `useState` function.

You can avoid this by declaring the state variables that should trigger the useEffect ensuring that those states are not changed in useEffect.